# How to manipulate SQL Query output

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if it's possible for example I have one sql table with the following results

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| ID |  Name   | Number | Active |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Jessica |     12 |      0 |
|  2 | Andrew  |     23 |      1 |
|  3 | Jason   |     53 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
```

And I would like to change the active field to `0 = No` | `1 = Yes` but only in the results, I don't want to change the value of the row, is it possible to make one query that can do it?

Well with the answers bellow I managed to get it changed but now how can I echo the value in php?

```
SELECT *, case when Active =0 then 'No' when Active =1 then 'Yes' end as Expr1,
FROM table
```

Should it be like: `$isActive = $rows['Expr1'];`
NVM the line above is working.

Comment: `select case Active when 1 then 'Yes' else 'No'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a case statement for translating 1 = yes and 0 = No like this

```
select ID 
      ,Name
      ,Number
      ,case when Active=0 then 'No'
            when Active=1 then 'Yes'
       end as active_y_n
 from table
```

Comment: For example if I would like to echo the Yes or no in PHP I would have to use the var `active_y_n`?

Comment: Would it be something like: `$isActive = $rows['active_y_n'];` and then `echo $isActive;`

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select Id,name,number,
case  Active when 0 then 'No'
    when 1 then 'Yes' end as active_status
    from t
```

Answer (score 0):

A particularly simple way would use `elt()`:

```
select Id, name, number,
       elt(Active + 1, 'No', 'Yes') as as active_status
from t
```